# How to use expression for field calculation in Access using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, expression, field

I would like to change the expression of a calculated field in Access using VBA. I have already managed to create a field whose values are being determined by an expression. I have used something along those lines:

```
sub test()

    Dim db As Database
    Dim fld As Field
    Dim tbl As TableDef

    set db=CurrentDb
    set tbl = db.TableDefs("tblMyTable")
    Set fld = tbl.CreateField("Identifier", dbText)
    fld.Properties("Expression") = "abc: " & "123"

end sub
```

What do I have to do to change the expression for the now already existing field "Identifier"?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub ChangeMyTable()
'Changing Сalculated Field Expression
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim td As DAO.TableDef
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim sExpression$
 
    sExpression = """" & CurrentProject.Path &  """"
    
    Set db = CurrentDb

    db.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblMyTable DROP Column Identifier"
 
    Set td = db.TableDefs("tblMyTable")
    Set fld = td.CreateField("Identifier", dbText, 100)
    fld.Expression = sExpression
    td.Fields.Append fld
    
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set td = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```